# Cannot find name ‘xdom2jso’ using Angular2-Soap in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a problem using Angular2-Soap in Ionic 2, i installed Angular2-Soap in my Ionic 2 blank project as following

`sudo npm install autopulous-angular2-soap`

Then in my **home.ts {Start Page}** i placed the following

`import {SoapService} from "autopulous-angular2-soap/src/soap.service";`

also in my **app.module.ts** i placed the following

`import {SoapService} from "autopulous-angular2-soap/src/soap.service";`

when i run `ionic serve` i get the following error

`[09:55:34] typescript: node_modules/autopulous-angular2-soap/src/soap.service.ts, 
            line: 1 
            Cannot find name 'xdom2jso'. 
            L1: import convert = xdom2jso.convert;
[09:55:34] typescript: node_modules/autopulous-angular2-soap/src/soap.service.ts, 
           line: 1 
           Cannot find namespace 'xdom2jso'. 
           L1: import convert = xdom2jso.convert;
[09:55:34] transpile failed`

in **node_modules** folder i see folders named **autopulous-angular2-soap**, **autopulous-xdom** and **autopulous-xdom2jso**

How can i solve `Cannot find namespace 'xdom2jso'`

any help will be appreciated.
Thanks alot.

Comment: Needed help. Got the same error here too. :(

Answer (score 1):

try insert

```
<script src="../node_modules/autopulous-angular2-soap/vendor/autopulous-xdom/xdom.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/autopulous-angular2-soap/vendor/autopulous-xdom2jso/xdom2jso.js"></script>
```

in src/index.html or src/app/app.html

Comment: What does this do? Why does it help?

Comment: in the documentation it asks you to import these two scripts into index.html so you can use xdom.js and xdom2jso

Comment: I have inserted both the above scripts. but still, i am getting the below exception.                                                                                           ERROR in E:/CCDT/Angular2-Application/angular2-soap/src/soap.service.ts (1,18):
Cannot find name 'xdom2jso'.
ERROR in E:/CCDT/Angular2-Application/angular2-soap/src/soap.service.ts (1,18):
Cannot find namespace 'xdom2jso'.
ERROR in E:/CCDT/Angular2-Application/angular2-soap/src/soap.service.ts (84,21):
 Type 'Document' is not assignable to type 'NodeListOf<Element>'.
  Property 'length' is missing in type 'Document'

Answer (score 0):

Old question and I have not been able to get SOAP working with Ionic, but I have been able to get past this point.

Change:

```
import convert = xdom2jso.convert;
```

To:

```
import xml2js from 'xml2js';
```

Change:

```
var response:{} = convert(responseNodeList[0], this.localName);
```

to:

```
var response:{} = xml2js.convert(responseNodeList[0], this.localName);
```